# Comparing numbers in strings to numbers in int?

Tags: c++, string, numbers, int, compare

I'm trying to make a program that will open a txt file containing a list of names in this format (ignore the bullets):

- 3 Mark
- 4 Ralph
- 1 Ed
- 2 Kevin

and will create a file w/ organized names based on the number in front of them:

- 1 Ed
- 2 Kevin
- 3 Mark
- 4 Ralph

I think I'm experiencing trouble in line 40, where I try to compare the numbers stored in strings with a number stored in an int.

I can't think of any other way to tackle this, any advice would be wonderful!

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    string line;
    string collection[5];
    vector <string> lines;
    vector <string> newLines;
    in.open("infile.txt");
    if (in.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
        exit(1);
    }
    out.open("outfile.txt");
    if (out.fail())
    {
        cout << "Output file opening failed. \n";
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!in.eof())
    {
        getline(in, line);
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
       collection[i] = lines[i];
    }

for (int j = 0; j < lines.size(); j++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < lines.size(); x--)
        {
            if (collection[x][0] == j)
            newLines.push_back(collection[x]);
        }
    }


for (int k = 0; k < newLines.size(); k++)
{
    out << newLines[k] << endl;
}

in.close( );
out.close( );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try casting them? Which language is this exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have included that in the post. It's c++. I just tried casting the variable j to a char and haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: You need ordered set or otherwise known as Set class objects so that you can store your sorted name records (use std::sort object for that). Try with these and update your code if you are still stuck. Just trying not to write code for you as you have shown effort to write things yourself.

Comment: I haven't worked with sets yet so I'm not too sure if I follow. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using a debugger would tell you where you went wrong, but let me highlight the mistake:

```
if (collection[x][0] == j)
```

You're expecting a string like `3 Mark`. The first character of this string is `'3'`, but that has the ASCII value of `51`, and that is the numerical value you'll get when trying work with it is this way! This will never equal `j`, unless you've got a lot of lines in your file, and then your search system will not work at all like you wanted. YOu need to convert that character into an integer, and then do your comparison.

C++ offers many way to process data via streams, including parsing simple datafiles and converting text to numbers and vice versa. Here's a simple standalone function that will read a datafile like you have (only with arbitrary text including spaces after the number on each line).

```
#include <algorithm>

// snip

struct file_entry { int i; std::string text; };

std::vector<file_entry> parse_file(std::istream& in)
{
    std::vector<file_entry> data;

    while (!in.eof())
    {
      file_entry e;

      in >> e.i; // read the first number on the line
      e.ignore(); // skip the space between the number and the text
      std::getline(in, e.text); // read the whole of the rest of the line

      data.push_back(e);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Because the standard way that `>>` works involves reading until the next space (or end of line), if you want to read a chunk of text which contains whitespace, it will be much easier to use `std::getline` to just slurp up the whole of the rest of the current line.

Note: I've made no attempt to handle malformed lines in the textfile, or any number of other possible error conditions. Writing a proper file parser is outside of the scope of this question, but there are plenty of tutorials out there on using C++'s stream functionality appropriately.

Now you have the file in a convenient structure, you can use other standard c++ features to sort it, rather than reinventing the wheel and trying to do it yourself:

```
int sort_file_entry(file_entry a, file_entry b)
{
    return a.i < b.i;
}

int main()
{
    // set up all your streams, etc.

    std::vector<file_entry> lines = parse_file(in);

    std::sort(lines.begin(), lines.end(), sort_file_entry);

    // now you can write the sorted vector back out to disk.
}
```

Again, a full introduction to how iterators and containers work is well outside the scope of this answer, but the internet has no shortage of introductory C++ guides out there. Good luck!

Comment: So, a full 'how to do c++' answer isn't really practical here, but let me go back through and edit my post a little and perhaps simplify a few things.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. I've only recently learned about structs so I don't follow completely yet. If for example I had a list that contained both the first and last name per line (ex. 3 Mark Wahlberg), would I still use in or would I use getline?

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't able to edit my last response until 5 minutes passed. I didn't read the note you made, please disregard the second part of that last comment.

Comment: @Ron, I've editted my code a little, and simplified some things. You are correct that if you wanted to read in whole chunks of text with whitespace in them, you'd need to use `std::getline`, or if you knew the format of your datafile was sensible you could do `in >> firstname; in >> lastname` etc.